# Google Cloud Storage appends header/footer to a text file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am using signed URLs to upload/download files to/from GCS.

Uploading files went fine, however when i try to download the file I can see a meta data header and footer are appended to the file, as in the attached screen shot.
The same happens to image files, which makes the image non-viewable.

Is there a way to ensure the file added to GCS does not get modified in anyway ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data appended to your upload is boundary markers. That means you are using the HTTP POST method with **Content-Type: multipart/form-data**.

> Data is sent as a block of data ("body part"), with a user
> agent-defined delimiter ("boundary") separating each part. The keys
> are given in the Content-Disposition header of each part.

To upload data using a Signed URL, use the HTTP PUT method or switch to Signed Policy Documents.

[Google Cloud Storage Policy Document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication/signatures#policy-document)